# WxPython: How to get the range of displayed cells in a wx grid?

Tags: grid, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to get the range of visible rows/columns on a grid. The grid can be scrolled, I want the first displayed row and the last displayed row on the screen. If the function could do the same with columns it would be a plus.

Right now I came up with this solution:

```
def GetVisibleRowsRange(self):
    """
    return the row number of the first and last visible rows
    """
    r = 0;
    max = self.GetNumberRows()
    while r < max and not self.IsVisible(row=r, col=0, wholeCellVisible=False):
        r += 1
    firstRow = r    
    while r < max and self.IsVisible(row=r, col=0, wholeCellVisible=False):
        r += 1
    lastRow = r
    return firstRow, lastRow
```

This only works if the first column is visible.

I was wondering if I Can get the range of visible row/columns directly by using the windows virtual size functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using wxPerl, and the following python code is untested.
This method works, but you might need to "[get a little creative using unbound methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14267495/218294)".

```
ux, uy = self.GetScrollPixelsPerUnit()
sx, sy = self.GetViewStart()
w, h = self.GetGridWindow().GetClientSize().Get()
sx *= ux ; sy *= uy

x0 = self.XToCol(sx)
y0 = self.YToRow(sy)
x1 = self.XToCol(sx + w, True)
y1 = self.YToRow(sy + h, True)
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, it works more efficiently. I added True as 'clipToMinMax' parameter in the last 2 calls to make it work.